# Kotlin implicit conversion?

Tags: kotlin

I just realize that you can actually compare String in Kotlin with `<` `>` or `<=` `>=`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBvh4.png)

But I cannot find the documentation about this? Is this undocumented?

Comment: Read this official documentation about [Ordering](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-ordering.html)

Comment: Note that even in Java strings implement `Comparable<String>`, so they can be compared with each other to e.g. sort a list. Operators like `<` and `>` is just a syntactic sugar to make it easier.

Answer (score 3):

This ends up calling `compareTo()`.  There is no implicit conversion occurring.

The documentation is here:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#comparison-operators

```
a > b     a.compareTo(b) > 0
a < b     a.compareTo(b) < 0
a >= b    a.compareTo(b) >= 0
a <= b    a.compareTo(b) <= 0
```

> All comparisons are translated into calls to `compareTo`, that is required to return `Int`.